# Why changing state (props based) in child component can effect the props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

You can see demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/v8r0yj4y8y). Try to click "Edit" button and change the value of input field.

In the parent component, it pass an array of objects to its child. Inside the child component, one of objects can be passed into its state, named `editedTodo`. But, strangely, the prop is changed when `editedTodo` is changed.

This is not what I want. Anyone can help me solve this?

Here is the `todo` Component:

```
import React from "react";

export default class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editedTodo: null
  };

  toggleEditTodo = (todo = null) => {
    this.setState({ editedTodo: todo });
  };

  onChangeTodoText = text => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      editedTodo: Object.assign(prevState.editedTodo, { text })
    }));
  };

  submitTodoForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.saveEditedTodo(this.state.editedTodo);
    this.setState({
      editedTodo: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { editedTodo } = this.state;
    const { todos } = this.props;
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>{JSON.stringify(todos)}</li>
        {todos.map(todo => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo === editedTodo ? (
              <form onSubmit={this.submitTodoForm}>
                <input
                  autoFocus
                  value={editedTodo.text}
                  onChange={e => this.onChangeTodoText(e.target.value)}
                />
                &nbsp;
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleEditTodo}>
                  Cancel
                </button>
              </form>
            ) : (
              <span>
                {todo.text}
                &nbsp;
                <button onClick={() => this.toggleEditTodo(todo)}>Edit</button>
              </span>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/3q1k4m3vm5

Here is the working version.

The problem was with `this.setState({ editedTodo: todo })`. You are assigning the same copy of `todo` from the props to the state. So it is referencing the same item. Make sure you are never mutating your props directly, it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks that solve the problem. However, I need to fix submit event. Again, thanks for your help.